# Creating separate Header for each if statement in Python

Tags: python

My code pulls data from a csv file. I want to add a header to it. I am confused where to put the print statement so it will be at the beginning of the file (as a header).

```
import csv
import StringIO

f = open('/home/unica/app/Affinium/Campaign/partitions/partition1/scripts/runscripts/campaigns/cnyr/dev/output/CNYR_DM_TM_CAMPAIGN_WAVES.csv', 'r')

try:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
if row[16] == "" and row[5].find('_NOEMAIL_'):
   if row[6]== 'DM':
      print('PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,CO_NAME,...
      print(  row[17]+'|'+row[16]+'|'+row[25]+'|'+row[18]+'|'+row[20]+'|'....
   elif row[6]== 'TM':
      print('PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,CO_NAME,...
      print(  row[17]+'|'+row[16]+'|'+row[25]+'|'+row[18]+'|'+row[20]+'|'....
```

there is multiple if statement and I want header before each case.So I was putting it after if and before printing the rows.The result which I am getting is

```
PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,...
,J,8,,NUSRALA,,EDWARD...
PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,...
,J,614,,BACAL,,LEON...
```

So definitely I wasnt asking for this.Seems it is searchng for every row in csv file and returning the "PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,..." every time it is looping over.Any idea how to fix this.

the csv file looks like this

```
SEQ_NUM|ICS_ORIG_STRT_DT|EDW_FIRST_OUT_IFP_DT|...
119|20140602|00010101|20140818|0|21...
119|20140602|00010101|20140818|0|21...
```

Also the o/p I want is like this

```
PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,...
,J,8,,NUSRALA,,EDWARD...
,J,614,,BACAL,,LEON...
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation; either get rid of that `try` or add the corresponding `except` or `finally`; fix the stray quotes and missing parens; etc. The code you've shown us won't actually run, or even compile, and is far from being an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @abarnett It runs and provides me the output with which I disagree.Please dnt worry about indentation.Help me to understand why it is happening.

Comment: @Rajarshi: Help us help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just print the header before the `for` loop:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
print(my_header)
for row in reader:
    do_stuff(row)
```

If the header is based on the first row of the CSV file, read that first row separately:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
header = next(reader)
do_header_stuff(header)
for row in reader:
    do_stuff(row)
```

---

Meanwhile, if you need the `csv` module for reading the file, you almost certainly need the `csv` module for writing out a processed version if it. Otherwise, you're going to break the exact same quoting, escaping, etc. that required the `csv` module in the first place.

And, even if you don't actually need it, it will make your code a whole lot simpler.

For example, find the error in each of these these two lines:

```
print(  row[17]+'|'+row[16]+'|'+row[25]+|'+row[18]+'|'+row[20])

writer.writerow((row[17], row[16], row[25, row[18], row[20]))
```

Comment: ty.I jumped into python so if you can explain a little more.for me the header is print('PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,CO_NAME,... and I want to include it before every if statement.So that when that particular if statement satisfy with my data it will return the data with the particular print statement.Hope it helps.

Comment: @Rajarshi: I think I understand your problem less after reading that description than before. This is exactly why we want an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Edit your question to give us a stripped-down, minimal example, with input, desired output, and actual output, and then we can show you how to change it. Without that, we're just guessing.

Comment: @Rajarshi: Your update still doesn't have compilable code. Also, I still don't understand how either rjbman's answer or mine is insufficient, since they both produce the output you say you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is printing it for every loop iteration. Try moving it to before the for statement.

```
print('PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,CO_NAME,...
for row in reader:
    if row[16] == "" and row[5].find('_NOEMAIL_'):
        if row[6]== 'DM':
            print(  row[17]+'|'+row[16]+'|'+row[25]+'|'+row[18]+'|'+row[20]+'|'....
        elif row[6]== 'TM':
            print(  row[17]+'|'+row[16]+'|'+row[25]+'|'+row[18]+'|'+row[20]+'|'....
```

Comment: Correct it is printing for each iteration.but the print statement is different for each if statements and I have multiple of them.So that when that particular if statement satisfy with my data it will return the data with the particular print statement on the top of it.

Comment: @Rajarshi so you want to stop going over each row once that is reached? If so, you might be looking for `break`.

Comment: I tried putting break and continue.ans also I put my print statement with the header with break and continue.Still it is printing.The code is running though.    if row[12]== 'DM':    break    print('PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM...     continue     print( row[17]+','+row[16]+',' ...

Comment: I would recommend reading through the Python documentation on [break and continue](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) so you can figure out exactly how they work. Debugging code without proper formatting is quite difficult, so you may want to consider updating your post (with proper formatting).

Comment: I did this.the code is running but not showing the printed statement.    if row[21] == "" and row[7].find('_NOEMAIL_'):
                if row[12]== 'DM':
                break
            print('PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,CO_NAME...continue
                print( row[17]+','+row[16]+','+row[25]+           elif row[12]== 'TM':
                break
                print('PRINT_PUB_CODE,PRINT_ACCT_NUM,CO... so on